# Excel spreadsheet checking which row contains contains data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vb.net application from which I open an excel spreadsheet that contains data. I copy all the data and insert it into sql server. I'm coming across a small issue with finding the last row. Here's how I've been doing it right now...

```
Dim lastRow As Long = 0
lastRow = xlws.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing).Row
```

This finds the last row for me but often times, the spreadsheet might contain data that is not relevant to what I'm trying to insert into my table - in this case it's a confidentiality statement at the last row of the spreadsheet. So what i'm trying to do is set the last row to whatever the last row of ACTUAL data is. This is what it looks like...

[image]

So in this case - i want the last row to be recognized to be row 11 rather than row 13. The thing is - the formatting of the report might be slightly different (for the confidentiality statement) so often times it might start in column A or B and be merged (possibly) or they might write it elsewhere.

Another thing is that Column A and B of data (ending at row 11) might sometimes not have a value. How should I go about something like this?

EDIT:
This is what I'm coming up with - Hate GoTo's but....

```
LastRowCheck:

  If CStr(excel.Cells(lastRow, 4).Value) = "" And CStr(excel.Cells(lastRow, 5).value) = "" And CStr(excel.Cells(lastRow, 6).value) = "" Then
                lastRow += -1
  goto LastRowCheck
  End If
```

Comment: quick and dirty : find last row for each row, then use `Max` to find the latest row, to ignore the type of data in row 13, check if `Max` last row is merged cell

Comment: If you can define how **you** *(the human)* determine the last row with data, we can code the VBA to make the same determination !

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - i understand so basically I want to set the last row to last row where first/last/dob columns contain data - because  those would always have something there

Comment: would you try `lastRow = xlws.Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` (adapt it to where you really expect some value for sure)...

Comment: @A.S.H see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub TheTrueLastRow()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, "B").Value = "" Or Cells(i, "E").Value = "" Then
            lastRow = i - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox lastRow
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Kinda came up with something similar please see edit. thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Sub Test()

    MsgBox LastRow(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2))

End Sub

Public Function LastRow(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Long

    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long
    Dim rCol As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    With wrkSht
        lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set rLastCell = .Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)

        'Look at each column, if the last cell is merged then look up from there,
        'otherwise leave the last row as it is.
        For Each rCol In .Range(.Cells(rLastCell.Row, 1), rLastCell).Columns
            If rCol.MergeCells Then
                LastRow = rCol.End(xlUp).Row
                Exit For
            Else
                LastRow = rLastCell.Row
            End If
        Next rCol
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

**Edit:** Just noticed, it will fail at this point (well, if the last column is shorter rather than the first two).

> Another thing is that Column A and B of data (ending at row 11) might
>   sometimes not have a value. How should I go about something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column that has data in each row of the table and the there is an empty cell between that on wanted data

xlws.Range("B1").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row

Alternately, you can take the bottom up approach if the only there is no unwanted data at the end of a column.

xlws.Range("B" & xlws.Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row

[image]
[image]